# Synonym creation for sequences in H2

Tags: h2, synonym

I am trying to create synonym for sequences in H2 ( version 1.4.200) but unable to create the same.
Error : the sequence for which we are trying to create synonym does not exist.

Comment: If you're talking about Oracle's synonyms, they don't exist in other DBMS, you should not ever think about their usage in cross-database applications. H2 supports synonyms for tables, however, for some limited compatibility with Oracle. You can't create a synonym for sequence in H2. Usually it's better to use identity columns instead of sequences.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov thanks for the update. However do you have any idea that was there any version ever in H2 which supported synonyms for sequences.